Order of pole of $(zI-A)^{-1}$ at eigenvalue.
Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ one of its eigenvalues. While reading this answer I was wondering what the order (denote it by $k_\lambda$) of the pole of $z\mapsto (zI-A)^{-1}$ at $z=\lambda$ is. The assertion in the answer is that it is at most the algebraic multiplicity. The order is the least $k$ such that $(zI-A)^{-1}(z-\lambda)^k$ stays bounded as $z\to\lambda$. By doing some examples I believe that the order is exactly the multiplicity $m_\lambda$ of $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial of $A$ and I think this could be verified without much difficulty using the Jordan form, but I don't like this argument very much as it rests on some explicit calculation in the case of a Jordan block, so I was wondering if anyone had a more conceptual argument for this.
For example, I was thinking that perhaps one could use the method in the linked answer to deduce this as follows: Let $f(z)=\prod_\lambda (z-\lambda)^{k_\lambda}$ where the product ranges over the eigenvalues of $A$. Then $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ is an entire function, so $2\pi if(A) = \int_\gamma f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz= 0$ (for a suitable curve $\gamma$), and therefore we get at least $k_\lambda\geq m_\lambda$. But it is not immediately clear to me if we can also use this to get the reverse inequality, for example if we would apply this to the minimal polynomial $m$ instead, we get $0 = 2\pi im(A) = \int_\gamma m(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz$ for large enough curves, but from this we cannot immediately deduce that $m(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ is entire, as there could be cancellation among the residues.
Also btw the question makes sense over arbitrary fields.

You don’t need full-fledged Jordan form. All you need is that the vector space is the direct sum of generalised eigenspaces of $A$. When $A$ is restricted to a generalised eigenspace corresponding to a different eigenvalue than $\lambda$, the map $z\mapsto(zI-A)^{-1}$ is holomorphic on an open set containing $\lambda$. Therefore, it suffices to consider the problem only on the generalised eigenspace for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. By a simple change of variable we may assume that $\lambda=0$ and $A$ is nilpotent. Let $m$ be the index of nilpotency of $A$. Then
$$
(zI-A)^{-1}
=z^{-1}\left(I-\frac{A}{z}\right)^{-1}
=z^{-1}\left(I+\frac{A}{z}+\frac{A^2}{z^2}+\cdots+\frac{A^{m-1}}{z^{m-1}}\right).
$$
Now $\lim_{z\to0}z^m(zI-A)^{-1}$ exists but $\lim_{z\to0}z^{m-1}(zI-A)^{-1}=\lim_{z\to0}(A^{m-2}+z^{-1}A^{m-1})$ does not, because $A^{m-1}\ne0$. Therefore the pole $z=0$ has order $m$.

This is good! I wanted to reduce to the case of just one eigenvalue, but somehow did not think about about restricting to a generalized eigenspace to accomplish that. Given this reduction, my original attempt using Cauchy's integral formula should also work. Let $f(z)=z^m$: Then $0 = 2\pi if(A) =\int_\gamma f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz$. Let $k$ be the order of the pole of $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ at $0$. We want to show $k=0$. If $k>0$, consider $g(z) = z^{1-k}f(z)$. Then $g(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ has non-zero residue at $0$, but the integral is still zero as $g(A) = 0$, a contradiction.

Indeed, the order of the pole of $R(z) = (zI - A)^{-1}$ at an eigenvalue $\lambda$ equals the multiplicity $m_\lambda$ of $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial. I cannot think of an elementary method of proving this, that does not require to collect some more information. I outline below a method that is presented in Kato's book on perturbations of linear operators, where to my surprise Kato does not mention the Cayley-Hamilton theorem at all, but proves a lot of facts about $R$.
The method comes down to exploiting Hilbert's identity $(w - z)R(z)R(w) = R(z) - R(w)$ in order to find relations on coefficients of the Laurent's series $R(z) = \sum_{k} A_k^{(\lambda)} (z - \lambda)^k$ at $\lambda$. The following statements can be proved by this method:

$A_{-1}^{(\lambda)}$ is a projection, $A_{-1}^{(\lambda)}A_{-1}^{(\mu)} = 0$ if $\lambda \ne \mu$, and $\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} A_{-1}^{(\lambda)} = I$.
$(A_{-2}^{(\lambda)})^k = A_{-1 - k}^{(\lambda)}$, $A_{-1}^{(\lambda)} A_{-2}^{(\lambda)} = A_{-2}^{(\lambda)} A_{-1}^{(\lambda)} = A_{-2}^{(\lambda)}$.
$A = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} (\lambda A_{-1}^{(\lambda)} + A_{-2}^{(\lambda)})$

In particular, Laurent coefficients give the Jordan's form of matrix $A$ and it is clear that the order of a pole of $R$ at $\lambda$ equals the number $k$ such that $(A_{-2}^{(\lambda)})^k = 0$ (that is, the nilpotency index of $A_{-2}^{(\lambda)}$).
Now moving to the minimal polynomial, we see that the range space $L_{\lambda} = A^{(\lambda)}_{-1}(\mathbb C^n)$ is an $A$-invariant subspace, on which it acts as multiplication by $\lambda$ plus a nilpotent operator. It is clear that the minimal polynomial for $A|_{L_\lambda}$ is $(x - \lambda)^k$, where $k$ is the nilpotency index for the nilpotent part of $A|_{L_\lambda}$ and we already identified $k$ as the order of pole of $R$ at $\lambda$. The proof finishes by observing that $A$ is a direct sum of operators $A|_{L_\lambda}$ and their minimal polynomials are relatively prime.
Finally, I think that the idea of the proof by considering polynomials $m$ such that $\int_\gamma m(z)R(z)dz = 0$ and arguing that there are no cancellations among residues is somewhat correct, since residues (as we see from statements 1 and 2) act as linear operators on different direct summands of $\mathbb C^n$ and have to be nullified independently. However, I can't think of a way that skips the first part of the proof, which seems to contain almost all technical details.

If you integrate on a positively-oriented circular contour $C$ that encloses one and only one pole $z$ of $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$--and no other singularities of the resolvent--then the following is a projection that commutes with $A$:
$$
             P=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda.
$$
Assume the order of the pole at $z$ is $k \ge 1$. Then
\begin{align}
        (zI-A)P&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(zI-\lambda I+\lambda I-A)(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda \\
        &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(z-\lambda)(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda \\
            & \cdots \\
       (zI-A)^kP&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}(z-\lambda)^{k}(\lambda I-A)^{-1}d\lambda = 0.
\end{align}
It follows that $(zI-A)P$ is nilpotent of order no greater than $k$ because the last integral has an integrand that is a function of $\lambda$ with a removable singularity at $z$. In particular, the range of $P$ is an eigenspace of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ iff $\lambda\mapsto (\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z$.
